# asp.net zero Web.Host deployment

Tags: asp.net, migration, zero

I have developed application in asp.net zero (asp.net core 2.0 and angular 5) and deployed on test server

1. published web.host application
2. deployed on IIS
3. able to access web site, now showing all api in swagger UI
4. but when try out any api link that gives me server 500 error

Question

1. How to run migration on my test server? OR will automatically run
   migration?
2. How to troubleshoot server 500 error on test server?
3. there is no any error in event viewer -> application
4. Didn't found deployment document of asp.net zero api explaining db migration on server where visual studio is not installed.

Thank you!

Prashant

Comment: I believe you can update connectionstring in your config file to point to host database (instead of local database) and then run the migrations. 
Once the migrations are run successfully you can check the api endpoints

Comment: How to run the migration on server, I don't have visual studio installed on server

Comment: If your database allow remote connections, you can update connectionstring to point to remote database and then run migrations using the visual studio installed on your local development machine

Comment: .net zero provided migratory.exe that we can use for migration on server